# How to reset admin password with drush and Acquia Dev Desktop?

Tags: drush, users

I realize that this is a pretty standard question that there is a lot of answers for elsewhere. The issue I have is that it seems that my drush commands aren't being reflected on my dev server.

I got locked out of my site, so I tried to use two methods to get in

1) drush upwd --password="mynewpass" "myuser"

and

2) drush ucrt "mynewuser" --password="mynewpass" followed by drush urol "administrator" "mynewuser"

Both command variations don't give me any errors and confirm the newly created user and his roles. Not sure what else I can do here. Before you ask, yes, I'm flushing my caches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's failing for you.
Probably check the error logs to see if there are any warnings or notices being logged there.

The latest versions of drush have `drush uli` which just gives you a one-time login link for admin.

$ drush uli
http://default/user/reset/1/1311169130/gf-1uDYC51jONONNF-jq3_ciKfLqhE93SsS9YNAnaEY
Unfortunately it doesn't get the hostname right in most cases (probably there's no way to know it if base_url is not set) so you have to change "default" correct hostname.

So in the case above, I would paste the link into a browser and then change it to

http://example.com/user/reset/1/1311169130/gf-1uDYC51jONONNF-jq3_ciKfLqhE93SsS9YNAnaEY
There I have a one-time login link to user 1 on the site. Works flawlessly.

You can also run drush as admin by adding this:

drush -u 1 "command"

Eg:

`drush -u 1 cc all`

Comment: ended up being a brain fart. I was jumping between environments and got mixed up. called the commands from the drupal root and everything was fine